# Suitable low-power ~10" graphical display options

Tags: display

I am looking for suitable display options for a battery-powered device, kind of like an e-book reader/tablet/mid device.

- size - 10" or so.
- resolution - preferably a high DPI
- colour - mono/gray
- static - low refresh rate/static is
  fine
- power - low enough to last 12 hours
  on a ~1000 mAH battery assuming 80%
  static usage.
- Brightness - readable in-doors, mainly.

I know of the existence of E-ink, Pixel-Qi and even ChLCD displays. I am wondering if there are any other display options available?

Comment: Hobby/prototype/production?

Comment: ultimately, production.

Comment: How much power can you spare for the display? Do you need colour? Is semi-static OK? Resolution?

Comment: I was going to recommend trying to get away with a custom segmented LCD, but if you want a 10" screen, that's a ton of real estate.

Comment: resolution - preferably a high DPI; colour - mono/gray; static - low refresh rate/static is fine; power - enough to last 12 hours on a ~1000 mAH battery assuming 80% static usage.

Comment: You are going to have a hard time buying something like this due to the rate at which phone and tablet manufacturers are ripping displays out of warehouses and shipping projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1000 mAh / 0.8 / 12 hours = about 100 mA, which is plenty. A parametric search on DigiKey landed half a dozen monochrome LCDs (*Display Modules - LCD, OLED, Graphic*), and they're all expensive ($200). First on the list is DMF-50036ZNBU-FW-BAN, which draws 30-40mA. I wouldn't recommend getting any of these as they are expensive, but you may be able to source similar ones from China.
I meant to put this as a comment to the OP, but I don't have the points yet.

Comment: This is a fine answer.  No reason to make it a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your requirements have narrowed it down to a display type you already listed: e-ink.  The others you mentioned all seem very experimental or in very specific applications.

I don't know how many e-ink manufacturers there are, but "E Ink Corp." has a [9.7" prototype kit](http://www.nexternal.com/eink/Product17) for sale (out of stock as of 2010 Nov 28).  You might also be able to hack a Kindle DX (same 9.7" screen), not sure what's in them.